# How can i check wso2 esb twitter connector

Tags: twitter, wso2, wso2-esb

I already created sample project for wso2 ESB twitter connector([method for create sample project](https://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS360/Creating+ESB+Artifacts#CreatingESBArtifacts-Workingwithsequences)) , but i don't know how to test that project in ESB (Create as Sequence Project).
[Twitter Connector Documentation](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Twitter+Connector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke the sequence, with respective operations used in the sequence, you will notice that the connector operations executed.

Answer (score 1):

better if you try with WSO2 developer studio, then you can easily create sequence with config.

http://sumuditha-viraj.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-use-wso2-developer-studio-cloud.html

here is another good article with practical usecase..

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/12/esb-connectors-in-action-enterprise-integration/